# Pointer-like logic in Rust

Tags: pointers, rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I need to move `n` elements from one `vec` to another, say `a` and `b`, in a pop/push loop. The tricky part is the following:

- if `n > 0`, I want to transfer `n` elements from `a` to `b`.
- if `n < 0`, I want to transfer `|n|` elements from `b` to `a`.
- `n == 0` isn't considered/will never happen/doesn't really matter.

Obviously, I want to check the condition only once, at the begining, and not in every iteration of the pop/push loop.

In a dynamic, "unsafe" language like Python, I would do it like this (which I believe is a very common pattern):

```py
if n > 0:
    from_ = a # `from` is a keyword in Python
    to = b
else:
    from_ = b
    to = a
# push/pop loop follows
# using the `from_` and `to` variables, not `a` and `b`
# ...
```

I cannot treat this problem in the same way in Rust, however, because the borrow checker does not allow it:

```
cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
```

I understand how the borrow checker works and why this isn't allowed. So, my question is, what is the Rustacean way to solve this?

Comment: [Why not](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d225d22eb8ed5607e33588ec00d8ea8)?

Comment: Though I'll probably use `let (from, to, n) = if n > 0 { (a, b, n as usize) } else { (b, a, -n as usize) }`.

Comment: Please provide the code that produces your error so answers can address what caused it.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to know what's going wrong if you provide no code, and fail to include 9/10th of the error message.

A trivial implementation seems to work fine:

```rust
fn move_items<T>(n: i32, a: &mut Vec<T>, b: &mut Vec<T>) {
    let (from, to) = if n > 0 {
        (a, b)
    } else {
        (b, a)
    };
    for _ in 0..n.abs() {
        to.push(from.pop().unwrap());
    }
}
```

it works just as well using "imperative" assignments:

```rust
fn move_items<T>(n: i32, a: &mut Vec<T>, b: &mut Vec<T>) {
    let (from, to);
    if n > 0 {
        from = a;
        to = b;
    } else {
        from = b;
        to = a;
    }
    for _ in 0..n.abs() {
        to.push(from.pop().unwrap());
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor nit, but you probably want `unsigned_abs` to handle `i32::MIN` and "escape" the signed range.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
let v1 = vec![77, 4, 33];
let v2 = vec![8, 41, 67, 33];
let (mut v_src, mut v_dest) = if condition { (v1, v2) } else { (v2, v1) };
```